# Stuck on unexpected container childnodes - javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me on Javascript coding? Lines13-14 i try to create 9x div(class="square") but i get 18 childnodes when i check container from console. It also prints 18 in total?

Second issue is about resetbutton. When i try to clear container childnodes to start a new game it gives error. (maybe there's no need to add some code to clear container?) Thank you.

```
// Create div elements inside container according to difficulty
for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
    container.appendChild(createDiv());
}

function createDiv() {
    // create a div element and assign "square" class
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.toggle("square");
    return div;
};

function resetGame () {
    // Clean boxes
    for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
        container.removeChild(container.childNodes[i]);
}
```

```js
var buttonReset = document.querySelector("#reset");
var container = document.querySelector("#boxes");
var difficulty = 9;
var h1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
var message = document.querySelector("#message");
var pickedColor = "";

// Listener for reset button
buttonReset.addEventListener("click", resetGame());

function newGame () {
    // Create div elements inside container according to difficulty
    for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
        container.appendChild(createDiv());
    }

    // Select all squares.
    var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

    // Create and fill colors array
    let colors = createColors();

     // Pick a random color from colors
    pickedColor = colors[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * squares.length)
    ];

    // Update text on screen
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

    // Draw squares with colors and check clicked color.
    for(let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        
        // Add initial colors to squares
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

        // Add click events to squares
        squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            // check if clickedColor is pickedColor.
            if (this.style.backgroundColor === pickedColor) {
                message.textContent = "Yes, you've found the color";

                //change all square colors to pickedColor
                for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
                    // Add initial colors to squares
                    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
                    };
                
                h1.forEach(function(item) {
                    item.style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
                });

                } else {
                    message.textContent = "Please try again!"
                    this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
                    }
        });
    };
}

function createColors() {
    let createdList = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
        createdList.push("rgb(" +
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ", " +
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ", " +
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")");
    };
    return createdList;
};

function createDiv() {
    // create a div element and assign "square" class
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.toggle("square");
    return div;
};

function resetGame () {
    /// Clean boxes
    for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
        container.removeChild(container.childNodes[i]);
    }
        

    // Create new game
    newGame();
};

newGame(); // Only for first run
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #232323;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}

.square {
    background: greenyellow;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    width: 30%;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
}

#stripe {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Color Game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="display-4">THE GREAT</h1>
  <h1 class="display-2"><span id="colorDisplay">RGB(175, 203, 2)</span></h1>
  <h1 class="display-4">GUESSING GAME</h1>

  <div id="stripe">
    <button id="reset">NEW COLORS</button>
    <span id="message"></span>
  </div>


  <!-- Color boxes -->
  <div class="container" id="boxes"></div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@2.0.0-next.4/dist/umd/index.min.js" integrity="sha384-AWosBrv7t83vzfQDzCZrtcVWT9tFVGuP7uL1EqwhTLscYSCGShI9+FOYrSL1wQYT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read this guide on [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem of having 18 divs instead of 9 in is because `newGame` method is called twice. One is at the end of code, the other one is in this line:

```js
// Listener for reset button
buttonReset.addEventListener("click", resetGame());
```

The `resetGame` method is called there but it should be just passed as it is:

```js
buttonReset.addEventListener("click", resetGame);
```

---

For the second problem of `resetGame` method not working as expected is that you are modifying the array that is being accessed (`container.childNodes`) in the loop.

1. That makes your `i` skip the element next to the each removed one.
2. Your `difficulty` may eventually become larger than `childNodesCount`

One solution is that do not remove items immediately, accumulate them in an array array and then remove based on that array

```js
const toBeRemoved = []

for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
  toBeRemoved.push(container.childNodes[i]);
}

toBeRemoved.forEach(child => {
  container.removeChild(child);
})
```

OR, another solution is that copy the childNodes to another variable so when you modify the original `childNodes` the copied array does not get affected:

```js
const arrayOfChildren = Array.from(container.childNodes)

for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
  container.removeChild(arrayOfChildren[i]);
}
```

After fixing both problems:

```js
var buttonReset = document.querySelector("#reset");
var container = document.querySelector("#boxes");
var difficulty = 9;
var h1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
var message = document.querySelector("#message");
var pickedColor = "";

// Listener for reset button
buttonReset.addEventListener("click", resetGame);

function newGame() {
  // Create div elements inside container according to difficulty
  for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
    container.appendChild(createDiv());
  }

  // Select all squares.
  var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

  // Create and fill colors array
  let colors = createColors();

  // Pick a random color from colors
  pickedColor = colors[
    Math.floor(Math.random() * squares.length)
  ];

  // Update text on screen
  colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

  // Draw squares with colors and check clicked color.
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {

    // Add initial colors to squares
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

    // Add click events to squares
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      // check if clickedColor is pickedColor.
      if (this.style.backgroundColor === pickedColor) {
        message.textContent = "Yes, you've found the color";

        //change all square colors to pickedColor
        for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
          // Add initial colors to squares
          squares[i].style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
        };

        h1.forEach(function(item) {
          item.style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
        });

      } else {
        message.textContent = "Please try again!"
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
      }
    });
  };
}

function createColors() {
  let createdList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
    createdList.push("rgb(" +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ", " +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ", " +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")");
  };
  return createdList;
};

function createDiv() {
  // create a div element and assign "square" class
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.toggle("square");
  return div;
};

function resetGame() {
  /// Clean boxes
  const arrayOfChildren = Array.from(container.childNodes)
 
  for (let i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
    container.removeChild(arrayOfChildren[i]);
  }


  // Create new game
  newGame();
};

newGame(); // Only for first run
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.square {
  background: greenyellow;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  width: 30%;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#stripe {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Color Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="display-4">THE GREAT</h1>
  <h1 class="display-2"><span id="colorDisplay">RGB(175, 203, 2)</span></h1>
  <h1 class="display-4">GUESSING GAME</h1>

  <div id="stripe">
    <button id="reset">NEW COLORS</button>
    <span id="message"></span>
  </div>


  <!-- Color boxes -->
  <div class="container" id="boxes"></div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@2.0.0-next.4/dist/umd/index.min.js" integrity="sha384-AWosBrv7t83vzfQDzCZrtcVWT9tFVGuP7uL1EqwhTLscYSCGShI9+FOYrSL1wQYT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick feedback!

Comment: If that answered your question, consider clicking on the gray checkmark on the leftside of the answer. Would be great if you would upvote it too